# Regex crashes Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I am experiencing a very strange problem.

Just some information first:
I am working on a detection function for mobile phone numbers.
I check the country and then comparing the phone numbers with this list:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_number_series_by_country#Italy

My problem is, that everything works fine, expect one phone number. For privacy reasons, I cannot provided here completely.

Example A: +49 172 8420***
Example B: +49 170 7900***

When I use my tampermonkey script on these phone numbers, everything works fine with example B. Example A leads into a crash of my whole browser.

Now it is getting interesting:
I made some debugging and found out, that the crash is caused by these lines:

```
else if(number.match(/^\+39/)) // Italy
{

    if(number.match(/^\+39[0]?(310|110[015]|31[39]|32[0234789]|33[013456789]|34[0123456789]|3440|3505|3510|350|36[12368]|370|371[01]|3740|37[37]|38[0123589]|39[01237])/))
        return mobile;
    else
        return landline;

}
```

As you can see, this case should action only for phone numbers which are starting with +39 but the crash happens on German numbers with +49.
The German numbers will be checked on about 60 lines later after some other countries.

Can someone explain me what is wrong with this part of code and why it leads into a crash?

Thanks in advance

Additional information:
I used before another code, which I optimized to the above code. The old one works like a charm on both phone numbers

```
        else if(number.match(/^\+39/)) // Italy
        {
            if(number.match(/^\+390310/) || number.match(/^\+3903110[015]/) || 
               number.match(/^\+39031[39/) || number.match(/^\+39032[023478/) || 
               number.match(/^\+39033[013456789]/) || number.match(/^\+39034[012356789]/) || 
               number.match(/^\+3903440/) || number.match(/^\+3903505/) || 
               number.match(/^\+3903510/) || number.match(/^\+390350/) || 
               number.match(/^\+39036[012368]/) || number.match(/^\+390370/) || 
               number.match(/^\+390371[01]/) || number.match(/^\+3903740/) || 
               number.match(/^\+39037[37]/) || number.match(/^\+39038[0123589]/) || 
               number.match(/^\+39039[01237]/))
                return mobile;
            else
                return landline;                
        }
```

Comment: Any jsfiddle with demonstration of the issue?

Comment: It's an intranet website. I cannot post a live example of how it is happening. I need to know in this case why this part is causing the crash because it should not be executed at all

Comment: It should not and it does not for us http://jsfiddle.net/a47o6ae4/